# Unable to boot : with linux mint or ubuntu : failed command read FPDMA queued.: /dev/sda2: unexpected inconsistency busybox v1.27.2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, boot, asus

I was using Linux Mint 19 on an [Asus X-550 LC](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X550LA/E_eManual_X550LA_LB_LC_VER7926.pdf?_ga=2.53815403.232053325.1560793506-1959752819.1554754024) laptop, and one fine day I got the error about some file system corrupted while booting. So I took the back up of all files using linux mint os on usb and then tried to erase everything and install linux mint again. It did not work so I took out the HDD and formatted it externally and again put it in and tried to install ubuntu 18.04. After completion, the laptop started but as soon as I restarted it, I got same error as previous so I think it might be a hardware issue like ram or hdd got corrupted. But I am not sure. Is there any way to find out whether it is RAM, HDD or some software issue.

Already tried:[image]Erasing everything on hard drive and installing linux mint. Removing HDD formatting it externally and installing ubuntu.
Edit1:
when I try to use live usb, it works well and I could get the backup of my data through it.Also, erase and install option of live usb goes through. So when I erase and install new os on my hard drive using live usb, it works for the time until I shut down and/or restart the laptop.

Comment: when I try to use live usb, it works well and I could get the backup of my data through it.Also, erase and install option of live usb goes through. So when I erase and install new os on my hard drive using live usb, it works for the time until I shut down and/or restart the laptop.

Comment: Yay! Backup good! To look for HDD trouble, what happens if you continue to use the LiveUSB for a couple of hours, copying files back/forth to/from the internal drive? You could use _stress_ or _stress-ng_ to automate that.

Comment: To look for memory trouble, suggest opening the plate underneath, removing and then reinserting the memory, following your manual's instructions in pages 94-96. Should that not resolve it, try substituting other memory of the same type. Should that not work, since your CPU is soldered to the main board, there's no way to remove/reseat it, but if you put it in the freezer in a sealed bag, let it freeze, and then power up, and it behaves for a while, you have a motherboard or CPU problem, both requiring the same solution: Replace the motherboard/CPU combo, or get another machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried replacing my HDD with new ssd and was able to install os and for last one day everything now is working fine! Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the answer was good, you might click on the up arrowhead in grey at left; if it was the best answer and it worked, also click on the checkmark. That shows folks what answers are useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since the system runs OK with a Live USB, please reinstall the OS on a replacement drive (SSD or HDD).